# Set PropertyGroup property to Exec output

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I would like my SDK-style project's assembly to automatically include the Git revision number in the `<VersionSuffix>`.

I feel like I'm close:

```xml
<Project>
    <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <VersionSuffix>UNSET</VersionSuffix>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
    
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command="git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitRevision"/>
        </Exec>
        <Message Text="HEAD is at $(GitRevision)" Importance="high"/>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <VersionSuffix>$(GitRevision)</VersionSuffix>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

```
dotnet publish XYZ -c Release
```

```
MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  9f3d8fb
  HEAD is at 9f3d8fb
  XYZ -> ...\bin\Release\net7.0\XYZ.dll
  XYZ -> ...\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\
```

You can see from the build output that it is correctly fetching the revision number and assigning it to `$(GitRevision)`. But it's not setting the `<VersionSuffix>` property like I want:

[image: Assembly's file properties, showing that the VersionSuffix property is still "UNSET"]

How do I set that property?

Answer (score 0):

I was assigning the wrong property. I should have instead been assigning to `InformationalVersion`.

It also isn't necessary to override any of the targets as shown in OP. Just use `InitialTargets` on the `<Project>` instead.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" InitialTargets="AssignInformationalVersion">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AssignInformationalVersion">
        <Exec Command="git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" StandardOutputImportance="low">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitRevision"/>
        </Exec>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <InformationalVersion>$(Version)-$(GitRevision)</InformationalVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```